# q: `': The pipe is being closed`

Tags: kdb

I'm using protected evaluation:

```
@[loopSizes[z]; z:0; {show "error thrown, returning zero", 0}]
```

Eventhough it works as expected, the console outputs:

```
': The pipe is being closed
```

What does this mean and how can I improve my code such that this doesn't happen?

Comment: A ":" assignment shouldn't be in a protected eval. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `loopSizes` is a function with a `do[]` inside which declares some local variables. Is that the problem?

Comment: Possibly. But dealing with the protected eval first, are you trying to do a protected run of the loopSizes function with zero as the input? If so, the syntax should be:

@[loopSizes;0;{show "error"}]

Comment: @terrylynch I tried that before, but it didn't seem to work. Might be because of some other `'type` error I was working on back then. I'll try this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@[loopSizes; 0; {0N!"error thrown, returning zero";}]
```

Not sure why you were setting z to 0 in the 2nd argument of `@` - just 0 suffices and gets passed to `loopSizes`. (so long as `loopSizes` is a monadic function).

`0N!` prints to console. Also see `-1!` to print to standard out.

Not sure why you have a 0 at the end of that string either.